# I've installed a gem - but can't find it in /lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've installed a ruby gem using the command line. When I try `gem list --local` it clearly shows that the gem is clearly installed on my machine.

However I want to make changes according to the documentation. According to the documentation (using `gem server` and then `http://localhost:8808/`), I should look for the gem under `/lib`.

However I cannot find it anywhere on my machine - I looked using my mac's finder so that I can then edit it using textmate, but nada.

Any ideas? Where should I look for the gem so I can edit/use it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `-d` flag to get detailed information.

```
gem list --local -d
```

For `uglifier`, for example

```
uglifier (1.3.0)
Author: Ville Lautanala
Homepage: http://github.com/lautis/uglifier
Installed at: /Users/deefour/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/gemsets/myapp

Ruby wrapper for UglifyJS JavaScript compressor
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the detailed info now, but still cannot find it in the finder, any ideas? it's under .rvm, but I cannot find that in the finder to open the gem in tetmate. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: I have no idea why you're trying to modify a gem this way (as soon as you run bundler again your changes will be overwritten), but the reason you can't find it in Finder is because Finder doesn't show hidden files/folders *(`.rvm/` is a hidden directory)*. You can `cd` into the folder and run `mate .` to open the directory in Textmate, or you can run `open .` to open the folder in Finder.

Comment: If you're trying to customize a Gem installed through `gem` or `bundler`, you should instead fork the gem source (assuming it's versioned through git), clone the fork locally, and point your `Gemfile` to the local copy of your repo in a `:development` group using bundler's `:file` argument. When you're done with your customizations and deploying, push your fork's changes to your remote, make sure there is a `:production` group in your `Gemfile` pointing to your fork using bundler's `:git` argument, and then deploy.

Comment: Hmmm... really? it restarts it? according to the documentation I need to include `access_key_id` under `::Base`; doesn't that mean I need to find the gem file and edit it?

Comment: Im sorry, Lucy; I have no idea what exactly you're trying to do. What is `access_key_id`? What is `::Base`? What gem are you working with? What documentation are you working from? Knowing none of this, I can **still** tell you, you do **not** need to be modifying the source of gems.

Comment: you should just be able to ReOpen the Gems Base Class in your app initializer and add the access key there. What is the gem you are using, that would help tell you how to initialize it.

Comment: `AmazonProductAdvertisingApi`

Comment: @Doon where do I find the app initializer?

Comment: Lucy, this is way outside the scope of this Question. I suggest accepting this answer, creating a new question, asking how to modify `AmazonProductAdvertisingApi::Base` in a rails initializer. For what it's worth, the `EXAMPLE.txt` explains how to do this https://github.com/completelynovel/amazon-product-advertising-api/blob/master/EXAMPLE.txt. An initializer is a file in `config/initializers/`.

Answer (score 2):

To find the location of a gem:

`gem which <gemname>`

For example with the `debugger` gem

`gem which debugger`

`/opt/ruby/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.5.0/lib/debugger.rb`

Comment: Didn't work.. I'm getting `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`, but the `-d` (see other answer) worked

Comment: Remember to replace <gemname> with the actual name of the gem. e.g. `gem show uglifier`

Comment: so `show` not `which`? (I did replace the <gemname> with the gemname)

Comment: I'm getting `ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library <gemname>`

Comment: How did you install the gem? If you installed it as `sudo` then maybe prefix this command `sudo gem which...`

Comment: I don't remember... but I tried `sudo` now and it didn't work either - same error message